# Send to Translation in Workflow (Auto activity) not sending in-workflow version

Tags: 2013, workflow, translation-manager

I need [1] to push *in-workflow* versions of content to a translation process.

At the moment we have a set-up whereby, in the Event system, we

- get to an activity in the workflow,
- suspend the activity,
- create a translation {workflow} bundle and
- send the items for translation
- on returning we complete the workflow bundle (to get the desired status)
- un-suspend the parent workflow process

In the 'send items for translation; step we've found that the Translation Manager doesn't appear to be **workflow aware** and there's nothing I see in the API or the Workflow Bundle management docs to state how to send the minor version and not the last full version of the content to the Translation Service.

Is this possible? Has anyone achieved this?

Thanks for any ideas/comments - in the meantime I'm reading more and seeing what I can do in the code (rather than re-design the process) so any comments would be great.

[1] Releases are very controlled and batched at (generally) monthly intervals. The content is signed off early in the process and the language variant must be released with the English; even if multiple translation cycles are a result.

---

### UPDATE

The code iterates through the parent bundle and adds items that are translatable (and fit other criteria) to the translation job and workflow bundle created dynamically in the Translation publication.

**Tridion 2013SP1 HR1 > Translation Manager Plugin > World Server**

---

### UPDATE (2)

The activity I'm trying to get the Translation step in is an *Automatic Activity* and I eventually realised that I can just re-assign the task to the user that the Translation Service runs under (not least as it the NT AUTH user). So

- updated the Workflow Service to run as the same user (MTSUser in fact) running the translation service

I still see item being checked in by the correct user and then being checked in by the workflow process - unfortunately it's still the **major** version form the parent item.

---

### UPDATE (3)

Simplified case added / respective question (from a 'manual' perspective)
[Send to Translation in Workflow (Manual activity) not sending in-workflow version](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14274/send-to-translation-in-workflow-manual-activity-not-sending-in-workflow-versio)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(same answer whether this is automatic or manually sent)

From SDL Tridion Support

> We did not support translating items in workflow in 7.1
>
> ...
>
> we did bring it into 8.1 fully supported - and also addressing a couple of issues that will be in 7.1 if it is "forced" to send minor versions for translation

Further to this I'm testing the code to confirm if the item being sent for translation is being done so by workflow and then telling TM to get in the in-workflow version if it has access. I'm sure I'll have questions elsewhere in TREX when it breaks other bits!

Comment: We've put quite some effort to make this work in Web 8, I was not expecting this to work in 2013 SP1 (7.1), but some people seem to believe it's possible

Comment: We've been informed it _may_ be possible but there could be conflicts along the way - (I would be very interested to hear of anyone that's tackled this issue) - given this risk of the unknown we're working with the client to see if the process can be tweaked; obviously we'd be happier to upgrade to Web8 and this is another valid reason. (in the meantime I'm working on the side to test out what I can do in the Event System in 2013 SP1 HR1.

Answer (score 2):

Translation Manager should pick up the minor version if it is in a step assigned to the user the Translation Manager service run as. If it is not assigned to this user, Translation Manager will only have access to the last major version.

Comment: This is what I'd originally thought - I'll double check the code and post here if we are already doing this -  otherwise  it will THE answer I wanted to hear!

Comment: Hi Lars, I've tried this but to no avail - I've added 'update (2)' above - could this be related to the way the translation bundle is created - are there any expectations? - we add the items in a bundle in the language layer, start a workflow on those and then add them to a translation job and complete the workflow on return.