# Send to Translation in Workflow (Manual activity) not sending in-workflow version

Tags: workflow, translation-manager

*Note that this question is specific to an easier to replicate/test scenario than the related question on automatic activities (linked below)*

We've

- SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1
- an updated item in workflow at v4.1
- Translation Manager configured for World Server Translation

We want

- v4.1 to be translated, not 4.0

Specific Config, for the purposes of testing we've

- Removed <del>all</del> relevant Event System <del>Config</del> triggers and
- Removed <del>any</del> Translation Manager plugins
- Service *Tridion Content Manager Workflow Agent* running as my domain user account
- Service *Tridion Translation Manager* running as my user
- Configured *TranslationManager.XML* `<ServiceTcmUserName>` as my domain user
- My domain user has Impersonation rights and
- My domain user has the component in an STARTed workflow activity in an open edit state

  - have also tried

    - with activity started and component not open
    - with activity not started
    - with minor version **removed from workflow** and sent

      - as per OOTB this is checked out to my user (as the user removing from the active workflow bundle)
    - with minor version **out of workflow** checked-in to a major version (at this point the correct content is sent, but it's now a major version and out of workflow)

      - furthermore, as the item was checked-in out of workflow it's not unapproved and cannot be published to the LIVE target anyway :(

The output from verbose logging on the Translation Manager Service shows nothing out of the ordinary, however, note the two logs below that indicate the Translation Manager service is retrieving the last full version and not the in-workflow version.

As I understand it, if the Translation Service and Workflow Service are running as the same user - this alone - should be sufficient to allow Translation Manager to pick-up the minor version.

Have I missed a configuration here or is there something specific I need to select / do in order to have the correct *minor* version translated?

Thanks for any comments...

```
2016-03-28T12:41:46 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{comp-to-translate}-v4
2016-03-28T12:41:46 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{comp-to-translate}-v4
```

...

```
2016-03-28T12:39:34 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation TcmClient proxy created for user "CBLOOM\saunders".
2016-03-28T12:39:34 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Disposing service client
2016-03-28T12:41:08 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  Heartbeat Generator Sending Application Monitoring heartbeat on port 20131
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  DeleteTranslationJobs   TcmClient proxy created for user "CBLOOM\saunders".
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  TcmClient proxy created for user "CBLOOM\saunders".
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Dequeuing Translation Job
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  DeleteTranslationJobs   Disposing service client
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetLoggedUser
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetLoggedUser
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=null key=tm:cache
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=null key=tm:cache
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Sending Translation Job "saunders - COMP CHECKED OUT TO TRANS USER 643" with id "1272" to the translation management system.
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.IsExistingObject tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-3233-8192
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.IsExistingObject tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-3233-8192
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetItemList.GetListXml tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-3233-8192
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetItemList.GetListXml tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-3233-8192
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{comp-no-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{comp-no-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetPathToRootOrgItem tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{comp-no-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetPathToRootOrgItem tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{comp-no-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{comp-to-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{comp-to-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetPathToRootOrgItem tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{comp-to-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetPathToRootOrgItem tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{comp-to-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:0-35-1 key=tm:TranslationConfiguration
2016-03-28T12:41:09 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:0-35-1 key=tm:TranslationConfiguration
...
2016-03-28T12:41:10 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:0-743-1 key=tm:TranslationConfiguration
2016-03-28T12:41:10 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:0-743-1 key=tm:TranslationConfiguration
2016-03-28T12:41:10 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{comp-no-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:10 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{comp-no-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:12 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetItemDataWithCache tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{schema-no-translate}-8
2016-03-28T12:41:12 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetItemDataWithCache tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{schema-no-translate}-8
2016-03-28T12:41:12 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetBluePrintChain tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{schema-no-translate}-8
2016-03-28T12:41:12 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetBluePrintChain.GetSystemWideList tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{schema-no-translate}-8
2016-03-28T12:41:13 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetBluePrintChain.GetSystemWideList tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{schema-no-translate}-8
2016-03-28T12:41:13 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetBluePrintChain tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{schema-no-translate}-8
2016-03-28T12:41:13 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:4-{schema-no-translate}-8 key=tm:TranslationSchema
2016-03-28T12:41:13 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:4-{schema-no-translate}-8 key=tm:TranslationSchema
2016-03-28T12:41:13 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{comp-to-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:13 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{comp-to-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:14 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetItemDataWithCache tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-29177-8
2016-03-28T12:41:14 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetItemDataWithCache tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-29177-8
2016-03-28T12:41:14 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetBluePrintChain tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-29177-8
2016-03-28T12:41:14 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetBluePrintChain.GetSystemWideList tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{schema-with-translatable-fields}-8
2016-03-28T12:41:14 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetBluePrintChain.GetSystemWideList tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{schema-with-translatable-fields}-8
2016-03-28T12:41:15 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetBluePrintChain tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{schema-with-translatable-fields}-8
2016-03-28T12:41:15 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:4-{schema-with-translatable-fields}-8 key=tm:TranslationSchema
2016-03-28T12:41:15 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:4-{schema-with-translatable-fields}-8 key=tm:TranslationSchema
2016-03-28T12:41:15 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:15 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:15 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Checking out the item with id "tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}".
2016-03-28T12:41:15 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.CheckoutItem tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:15 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.CheckoutItem tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:15 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry WorldServerTranslationSystemJobRequest.PrepareTranslationJobForCompletion.createProjectGroup jobRequestId=SCOLVMCMSS01__1272_20160328124115, projectTypeId=1033
2016-03-28T12:41:21 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit WorldServerTranslationSystemJobRequest.PrepareTranslationJobForCompletion.createProjectGroup jobRequestId=SCOLVMCMSS01__1272_20160328124115, projectTypeId=1033
2016-03-28T12:41:21 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=null key=tm:cache
2016-03-28T12:41:21 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=null key=tm:cache
2016-03-28T12:41:21 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  The item with id 'tcm:{from-pub}-{comp-to-translate}' has been added to the translation management system job '2320'.
2016-03-28T12:41:21 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Tms job 2320 prioritized to be dequeued earlier
2016-03-28T12:41:21 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate} key=tm:TranslationInfo
2016-03-28T12:41:21 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate} key=tm:TranslationInfo
2016-03-28T12:41:21 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.IsExistingObject tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}-v0
2016-03-28T12:41:21 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.IsExistingObject tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}-v0
2016-03-28T12:41:21 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.SetAppData tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate} key=tm:TranslationInfo
2016-03-28T12:41:21 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.SetAppData tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate} key=tm:TranslationInfo
2016-03-28T12:41:21 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Entry CoreServiceProxy.SetAppData tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}-v0 key=tm:TranslationInfo
2016-03-28T12:41:21 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Exit CoreServiceProxy.SetAppData tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}-v0 key=tm:TranslationInfo
2016-03-28T12:41:22 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Posting translation management system job 2320
2016-03-28T12:41:22 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  No SMTP server is configured, notification email will not be sent.
2016-03-28T12:41:22 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Dequeuing Translation Job
2016-03-28T12:41:22 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Disposing service client
2016-03-28T12:41:34 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation TcmClient proxy created for user "CBLOOM\saunders".
2016-03-28T12:41:34 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetLoggedUser
2016-03-28T12:41:34 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetLoggedUser
2016-03-28T12:41:34 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=null key=tm:cache
2016-03-28T12:41:34 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=null key=tm:cache
2016-03-28T12:41:34 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Starting retrieving items for: Client id "WS:1035:CL:1033", translation management system Job ID: "2320"
2016-03-28T12:41:34 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry WorldServerConfiguration.GetJobItemStatus.getProjectGroup 2320
2016-03-28T12:41:37 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit WorldServerConfiguration.GetJobItemStatus.getProjectGroup
2016-03-28T12:41:37 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry WorldServerConfiguration.GetJobItemStatus.getProjectGroup.getProjects
2016-03-28T12:41:37 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit WorldServerConfiguration.GetJobItemStatus.getProjectGroup.getProjects
2016-03-28T12:41:37 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry WorldServerConfiguration.GetJobItemStatus.getProjectGroup.getProject 2336
2016-03-28T12:41:38 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit WorldServerConfiguration.GetJobItemStatus.getProjectGroup.getProject
2016-03-28T12:41:45 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry CoreServiceProxy.SetAppData tcmUri=null key=tm:WorkflowDefinition:1049
2016-03-28T12:41:45 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit CoreServiceProxy.SetAppData tcmUri=null key=tm:WorkflowDefinition:1049
2016-03-28T12:41:45 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=null key=tm:cache
2016-03-28T12:41:45 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=null key=tm:cache
2016-03-28T12:41:45 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Retreiving translation management system item with id "cmpx0" for language "1047".
2016-03-28T12:41:45 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry WorldServerTranslationSystemItem.RetrieveItem.download targetPath=/Clients/{client-path}/Projects/2320_saunders - COMP CHECKED OUT TO TRANS USER 643/Target-Spanish (United States)/grouped item properties.cmpx
2016-03-28T12:41:46 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit WorldServerTranslationSystemItem.RetrieveItem.download targetPath=/Clients/{client-path}/Projects/2320_saunders - COMP CHECKED OUT TO TRANS USER 643/Target-Spanish (United States)/grouped item properties.cmpx
2016-03-28T12:41:46 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{comp-to-translate}-v4
2016-03-28T12:41:46 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{comp-to-translate}-v4
2016-03-28T12:41:46 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetItemDataWithCache tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{schema-with-translatable-fields}-8
2016-03-28T12:41:46 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetItemDataWithCache tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{schema-with-translatable-fields}-8
2016-03-28T12:41:46 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetBluePrintChain tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{schema-with-translatable-fields}-8
2016-03-28T12:41:46 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetBluePrintChain.GetSystemWideList tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{schema-with-translatable-fields}-8
2016-03-28T12:41:46 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetBluePrintChain.GetSystemWideList tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{schema-with-translatable-fields}-8
2016-03-28T12:41:47 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetBluePrintChain tcmUri=tcm:{from-pub}-{schema-with-translatable-fields}-8
2016-03-28T12:41:47 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:4-{schema-with-translatable-fields}-8 key=tm:TranslationSchema
2016-03-28T12:41:47 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:4-{schema-with-translatable-fields}-8 key=tm:TranslationSchema
2016-03-28T12:41:47 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetPathToRootOrgItem tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:47 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetPathToRootOrgItem tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:47 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:47 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:47 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Storing retrieved translation in the item with id "tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}".
2016-03-28T12:41:47 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate} key=tm:TranslationInfo
2016-03-28T12:41:47 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate} key=tm:TranslationInfo
2016-03-28T12:41:47 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{translatable-keyword}-1024
2016-03-28T12:41:47 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{translatable-keyword}-1024
2016-03-28T12:41:47 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry CoreServiceProxy.CheckoutItem tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:47 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit CoreServiceProxy.CheckoutItem tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:47 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry CoreServiceProxy.UpdateXml tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:49 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit CoreServiceProxy.UpdateXml tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}
2016-03-28T12:41:49 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry CoreServiceProxy.CheckinItem tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}-v0
2016-03-28T12:41:49 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit CoreServiceProxy.CheckinItem tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}-v0
2016-03-28T12:41:49 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry CoreServiceProxy.IsExistingObject tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}-v0
2016-03-28T12:41:49 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit CoreServiceProxy.IsExistingObject tcmUri=tcm:{es-pub}-{comp-to-translate}-v0
```

Related question but specific to automatic activities: [Send to Translation in Workflow (Auto activity) not sending in-workflow version](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14202/send-to-translation-in-workflow-not-sending-in-workflow-version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From SDL Tridion Support

> We did not support translating items in workflow in 7.1
>
> ...
>
> we did bring it into 8.1 fully supported - and also addressing a couple of issues that will be in 7.1 if it is "forced" to send minor versions for translation

Further to this I'm testing the code to confirm if the item being sent for translation is being done so by workflow and then telling TM to get in the in-workflow version if it has access. I'm sure I'll have questions elsewhere in TREX when it breaks other bits!